# Bootstrap .table-responsive disable vertically scrollbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using the .table-responsive for my table. Since I have a lot columns so it does the magic. However, it also applied the scroll bar to my table vertically. How can I disable the vertical scroll bar and only keep the horizontal one?

Answer (score 6):

Getting this resolved by setting

```
.table-responsive {
  // Other values...
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  // Other values...
}
```